# Conditional query where there is no text to search

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is a follow up from a previous question to allow for code. I want to pass through params, when there is text then it works, when there is no text then I get no results. If there is no text and just a date then the query should return all documents where date = that value.

```
var query;

if(!req.query.text){
    console.log("no text")
    query = Record.find({})
} else {
    console.log("YES text")
    query = Record.find(
        { $text : { $search : req.query.text } },
        { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
    ) 
}




if(req.query.year){
    var years = req.query.year.split(',');
    if(years.length < 2){
        query = query.where('date.year', req.query.year)
    } else {
        query = query.where('date.year').gt(years[0]).where('date.year').lt(years[1]);
    }
}
if(req.query.loc === 1){
    query = query.exists('loc')
}
query
    .select('title date.year')
    .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
    .limit(50)
    .exec(function(error, results) {
        res.json(results)
 });
```

My noob console logging is working so the if statements work but the query builder seems not to like what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out. It is this line, no text, no text score. Simple.

```
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
```